# How to find the non-SEF URL whilst SEF is enabled (Joomla 1.5)?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-sef-urls

I know you probably don't get many questions like this...

I am working on a component that I want to be able to deal with the non-SEF URLs whilst SEF is enabled, whether it be the built-in SEF or something like sh404sef.

**Does Joomla store the ORIGINAL non-SEF URL anywhere** ie. index.php?com=com_fred&view=homepage?

I've found that any SEF activated, changes the JURI::getInstance() value to the SEF equivilant.
I've also found the the $REQUEST['URI'] value does not work on all platforms/servers etc.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Don’t you rather mean `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Answer (score 4):

1. Get all vars from the `GET/POST` request into an array. At this point you may also modify the values before generating the URL string.

   ```
   $getVars = JRequest::get( 'GET' );
   ```
2. If you really need the URL string, you can obtained with:

   ```
   $newURL = http_build_query($getVars);
   ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

I came back to this code and tried again but gave me some errors, so I've reworked it partially based on the previous answer I've formulated before with this new one (working nice on Joomla! 3.4.5)

```php
// build the JInput object 
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
// retrieve the array of values from the request (stored in the application environment) to form the query 
$uriQuery = $jinput->getArray();
// build the the query as a string
echo 'index.php?' . JUri::buildQuery($uriQuery);
```

Joomla! API Docs: [`JInput`](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JInput.html) - [`JUri`](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUri.html)

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**
Googling around [I found this](https://snipt.net/esedic/get-real-joomla-url-from-a-sef-url/):

```php
<?php
  // "unparse" the Joomla SEF url to get the internal joomla URL
  JURI::current();// It's very strange, but without this line at least Joomla 3 fails to fulfill the task
  $router =& JSite::getRouter();// get router
  $query = $router->parse(JURI::getInstance()); // Get the real joomla query as an array - parse current joomla link
  $url = 'index.php?'.JURI::getInstance()->buildQuery($query);
?>
```

I've tested it with Joomla! 3.4.4 and its working fine! Dunno if it can work with 1.5

Answer (score 3):

You can use JRequest::get(true) to get an array of all the query parameters from the URL. A quick note though, I haven't checked it enough to know if it only returns GET parameters or it does all REQUEST parameters (which I think is more likely). It might, however, help with what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For menu items, it's stored in the 'jos_menu' table, in the 'link' column (but the itemid is not in this string - it's the 'id' column).

For anything else, it's probably not stored in the database, but can normally be worked out pretty easily, especially with core components. It can be a little bit of a pain with third party components, but you can look through the MVC architecture of most components to figure it out.

Otherwise, you could always turn off SEF on your dev site/create a dev site for this.

Is there a specific component that you're curious about?

Answer (score 0):

The link that I posted here:
[Joomla URLs: An article doesn't have a pretty URL by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113634/joomla-urls-an-article-doesnt-have-a-pretty-url-by-itself/9427083#9427083)

provides a very good "crash course" for URLs in Joomla 1.5

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special for non-SEF URLs. Even if you have SEF URLs turned on, Joomla will still display the correct page if someone access the site with a non-SEF URL. The portion of your component that handles SEF URLs, the router, only tells Joomla how to use the URL information to determine what to display. When presented with a non-SEF URL Joomla just parses the query string as it normally would.

For any given component, the URL is built like this -

index.php?option=com_name&view=XXXX&id=1111&Itemid=11111

- option is the name of the component
- view is of course which view to display
- id is the id of the particular content item
- itemid is the menu item it used to determine module/template assignment